# Git: how to choose code changes from a remote

Tags: git

If I do  `git push origin develop`
I get in this situation:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
```

Ok, as expected, I understand there is stuff on the remote so I will need to do
`git fetch` and `git merge`, or `git pull`.

Now the point is that I want to examine the code and import only the changes that suit me and disregard others.

Please how do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: *import only the changes that suit me and disregard others.* that will not get rid of the hint message

Comment: no?? :-( what should I do instead?

Comment: Pull in all the changes

Comment: but if I do that I might import something that I don't want :-(

Comment: Why would you not want some of the changes?

Comment: If you don't want to collaborate with others on your code, why are you sharing a repository?

Comment: @LisaAnne was the answer below helpful?

Comment: @TonyBarnes yes Tony, upvoted, will accept if nothing else better comes +1 thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't really 'ignore' or disregard changes from the remote. Git/repos are collaborative and what you're asking for kind of defects the purpose of it.

Like you mentioned, you need to get the latest from remote, but you should merge changes rather than ignoring them.

If you `git pull` or `git merge`, git will tell you about any merge conflicts, and you can fix them.

Or, you could fetch and rebase (presuming you're on your own branch):

```
git fetch origin master
git rebase origin/master
```

or in one line:

```
git fetch origin master && rebase origin/master
```

This will put your changes on top of the remote changes, and will alert you of any conflicts, that you can fix step-by-step. You should fetch and rebase regularly.

During a rebase, if you have issues and you do want to choose your copy of a file, or the remote copy of a file, you could do one of these:

```
git checkout --theirs js/someScript.js

git checkout --mine js/someScript.js
```